# One-liner for explode with multiple delimiters

Tags: php, explode

Is there a nice looking one-liner to explode the following:

```
 $my_string = '0:abcd1234,0:wxyz9876,1:defg5678';
```

With the expected result:

```
array(
      [0] => array([0] => 0, [1] => 'abcd1234'),
      [1] => array([0] => 0, [1] => 'wxyz9876'),
      [2] => array([0] => 1, [1] => 'defg5678')
)
```

I know I could just `$my_array = explode(',', $my_string)` and then loop over the retrieved array and `explode(':', $my_array[$i])`, but I wonder if there's a more nicer looking way (without looping) to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use loops, just use array_map:

```
array_map(function($str) {return explode(':',$str);}, explode(",",$my_string));
```

If you're using PHP 7.4 it becomes even more shorter:

```
array_map(fn($str) => explode(':',$str), explode(",",$my_string));
```

Comment: Thanks this looks pretty nice. And while I'm still on 7.2, I really like that you've added a solution for 7.4 as well!

Comment: 7.4 not live yet (ETA is November 2019)

Answer (score 2):

Do it with one liner and nicer looking way by using `array_map()`,

```
$my_array = array_map(function($val) {return explode(':', $val);}, explode(',', $my_string));
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/ti3Aq